# NSTextAttachment doesn't show on CATextLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, nstextattachment

I tried it on UITextView it work. but the image left blank when i use CATextLayer.

anyone tried before?

here is the code i tried in UIView drawRect

```
NSTextAttachment* attachment = [NSTextAttachment new];
attachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rainbow.png"];
NSAttributedString* imageString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];
NSDictionary * attribute = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]};
NSMutableAttributedString *speechString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"hi" attributes:attribute];
[speechString insertAttributedString:imageString atIndex:1];
[speechString appendAttributedString:imageString];
```

Then add to CATextLayer

```
CATextLayer * speechTextLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
[speechTextLayer setString:speechString];
[speechTextLayer setFrame:self.bounds];
[speechTextLayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
[self.layer addSublayer:speechTextLayer];
```